# Merge a list containing numpy and numbers to one numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following list I want to turn into one numpy. What is the best and most effective way to do this?

```
[[array([1, 2, 3]), 1], [array([1, 2, 3]), 2], [array([1, 2, 3]), 4], [array([4, 4, 4]), 3]]
```

Expected result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [4, 4, 4, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
test = [[np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1], 
        [np.array([1, 2, 3]), 2], 
        [np.array([1, 2, 3]), 4], 
        [np.array([4, 4, 4]), 3]]

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:np.hstack((x[0],[x[1]])),axis=1,arr=test)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arrays = [[np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1], [np.array([1, 2, 3]), 2], [np.array([1, 2, 3]), 4], [np.array([4, 4, 4]), 3]]

new_array = np.empty([0, 4])
for i in range(len(arrays)):
    new_array = np.vstack((new_array, np.append(arrays[i][0], arrays[i][1])))
    
print(new_array)
```

```
array([[1., 2., 3., 1.],
       [1., 2., 3., 2.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [4., 4., 4., 3.]])
```